# Pass command line arguments with spaces to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, command-line-arguments

I wish to pass string data as arguments to an Excel program via cmd. Each argument may contain spaces. If the argument starts with any letter but ‘a’, the program tries to load the part of the string following the space an Excel program.

```
start "" excel.exe "C:\Test.xlsm"/aaa aa

start "" excel.exe "C:\Test.xlsm"/bbb bb
```

The former cmd runs OK. The latter cmd produces the error message:"'bb.xlsx' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct."

Inserting quote marks does not solve the problem.

Comment: Where are you inserting the quotes? What arguments are you trying to pass?

Comment: It's not clear what you're passing as arguments.  But if you wrap everything in quotes, you'll probably be fine. Be more explicit about what you're trying to accomplish and the format of your command.

Comment: The argument is a descriptive file name of a scanned image that will be used by the Excel program to compose text to be inserted onto the image for posterity.

…/"CapeCod1939" works
…/“Cape Cod 1935” does not 

Thanks